# Java interface with generics with bounded parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a requirement where I need to use generics as client can use their desired datatype when using my service. The code looks like:

```
public interface MyService<T extends Base> {

    void meth1(T type);
}

@Service("abc")
public class MyServiceImpl<T> implements MyService<T extends Base> {

    @Override
    public void meth1(T type) {
    }
}
```

where Base is a abstract class. the clients will use a subclass of it to call this service.

```
public abstract class Base {
}
```

Issue: The implementation class(MyServiceImpl) doesn't compile. I am not sure about the problem here.

Clients will use this service and push their datatypes which is subclass of Base. e.g something like this:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("abc")
    private MyService<xx> service;


service.meth1(xx)  //where xx is subclass of Base
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here. Please suggest.

Comment: A generic `Service` is a bad idea. It will just end up at the bound. If you were planning to configure it in an `@Configuration` with an `@Bean` it would make sense - but in your case the service needs to not be generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type bound should be in the declaration of the type parameter:

```
public class MyServiceImpl<T extends Base> implements MyService<T>
```

Comment: Worth noting that a generic service impl that is autowied by Spring serves little to no purpose as Spring has no way of knowing what generic argument to set.

Comment: Hi Eran, Thanks. This works as I expected. One advantage of this is that it restricts the clients to a particular datatype. Thus help in coding to a particular type and avoid issues
e.g     
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("abc")
    private MyService<XX> service;
 
 service.methd1(XX);  //allows only XX and its subtypes

Comment: One more observation. Spring magically gives me a different  bean instance based on the bound parameter. I was expecting below to be a issue but it worked fine.   

    Autowired
    Qualifier("abc")
    private MyService<XX> service;

    Autowired
    Qualifier("abc")
    private MyService<YY> service1;

 //Below calls works great without issues
 service.meth1(XX);
 service1.meth1(YY)
 
 Here XX, YY are 2 different POJOs extending from Base